# how to upload jpg image in robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to upload jpg image in robot framework but it's showing "element not interactable". can anyone help me in this?

```
*** Variables ***
${FILE_PATH}    C:/Users/rahul.yadav/Desktop/flower photo.jpg
*** Test Cases ***
upload photo
    Sleep  3
   Set Focus To Element        xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]

  Scroll Element Into View    xpath://*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2] 

   Choose File   xpath: //*[@id='content']/app-lead-sale/div/div/app-lead/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/app-customer-basic-details/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]        ${FILE_PATH}
  Sleep  2
```

The above results in this error:

```
Error: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.110)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkrv3.png)

Comment: i didn't get any solution. kindly help.

Comment: Your question is hard to read and understand, expecially, what is code and what is your comment. Try to use code highlighting: [Edit] your question and use either 4 leading spaces or fence code with ``` (3 backticks on either end + newlines)

Comment: hi can i share the complete code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.